# Android map api - changing zoom level causes incorrect marker position

Tags: android, zooming, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

Sorry if this was asked before.. it seems so obvious problem but could not find any reference.

When adding marker to the map - not even custom one, just plane marker, and zooming in/out, the marker image "floats" around to different positions, even to different states! I am passing the proper Double to the lat/long etc.. zooming all the way in gets you to the correct place.

Looking at Google's own services such as Google+ location sharing, it seems to work fine for them.. so not sure what to make of it.. are they re-calculating the anchor for each zoom level? hmm

Appreciate any help!
Thanks,
Udi

Comment: Please show some code it will help us understand whats happening.

Comment: The code is super simple -

Comment: LatLng myPlace = new LatLng(friendLat, friendLng);

Comment: friendMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
  .title(nameStr)
  .snippet("OK were are here!")
  .position(myPlace)
  .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(myBitmap))
  .alpha(0.7f)
  .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f));

Comment: The only thing I can see from what you have posted that could cause this is the anchor. What you have set is the middle of the pin, is this what you want? Edit: middle as in vertically AND horizontally (most pins want an anchor of (0.5, 1))

Comment: Thanks.. I tried to move the anchor all over the place, 0/0, 1/1 and anything in between .. does not seem to have much difference - the icon still seems to float around .. btw the same thing happens also on my JavaScript with similar code... so seems like it's inherent issue in the map support(?) when you add marker does it stay in place when you zoom? thanks!

Comment: Yep I use markers pretty extensively in my app (with all kinds of animation and what not) but they stay still when zooming. I can't see anything else in your code that could be causing this except the anchor.

Comment: Do you have to play with the anchor using the zoom listener or something like that?

Comment: It might be my icon, I saw some posts where the map does not like certain type/sizes I think ..

Comment: I set my anchor to (0.5, 1) (which is the bottom verticall and center horizontally) and it stays there. You shouldn't have to change anything when zooming around, Maps should handle this for you.

Comment: I will try with your 0.5/1 anchor, and try default image... thanks

Comment: Yeah it's the image :) I used Google's default image and it's rock solid, then I copied the Google's default pin image and used it as my image, no params at all (size/origion/scale etc.. the JavaScript version) - again rock solid in zooming. Their png is 25x42 pix or so, mine is little bigger, 60x75 pix.. I guess I can shrink mine but that does seem like a bug.. unless there is some workaround using the anchor / scale params that I am missing etc..

Comment: I wonder of you or anyone else tried icons bigger then 25x45 or so.. location seems to messed up in zooming

Comment: Yep, I use pins that are bigger than that - cant remember the size exactly but they are definitely bigger; they have profile pics in them. Have you tried your image without any of the params?

Comment: Yes I did .. does not seem to make difference .. it only apparent when you zoom from very close and out..

Comment: Do you have transparent pixels below the pin your icon image?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem adding `marker.anchor(0,0);` Fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem when adding marker to google map, the problem is wrong bitmap when try to convert  and resize drawable resource, just use this:

```
    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    ...
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_merchant_location)));
```

You could check [official Android Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker)